# Detect if iOS Intelligent Tracking Prevention is disabled

Tags: swift, wkwebview, ios14

Due to iOS 14 defaulting Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP) on, I would like to display a message in a `WKWebView` explaining how to disable ITP. I do not want them to see the message otherwise (although they have to see it once).

There does not appear to be a way to check if ITP is in play, and I would like to prevent users from seeing the message if they've changed the setting.

How could I prevent the message from displaying if they have changed the setting?

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem was to detect if a cookie had actually been written and modify the landing/pass-through url accordingly.

```
private func loadWebView() {
    load(skipInstructions: false)
    
    webView?.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies({ (cookies) in
        var skipInstructions:Bool = false
        
        cookies.forEach { (cookie) in
            skipInstructions = skipInstructions ? skipInstructions : cookie.domain == "api.example.com"
        }
        
        self.load(skipInstructions: skipInstructions)
    })
}

private func load(skipInstructions: Bool) {
    let url = skipInstructions ? URL(string: "\(self.landingUrl)?skip-instructions")! : URL(string: "\(self.landingUrl)")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.splashScreen)
    self.webView?.load(request)
}
```